# Use PHP Array and Subarray to generate Strings

Tags: php, arrays, string

### EDIT

I went back out on safari and found this webpage: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php6p5.html

They presented a different style of Array ( below ) and their output looked similar to what I wanted. I found that I *was* able to get first and last names as individual variables within the foreach!

```
$full_name = array( );

$full_name["David"] = "Gilmour";
$full_name["Nick"] = "Mason";
$full_name["Roger"] = "Waters";
$full_name[""] = "";
$full_name["Richard"] = "Wright";

foreach ($full_name as $firstName => $lastName) {
    if ($firstName != '') {

        $fn = $firstName;
        $ln = $lastName;

        $sn_display = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
        $sn_slug = $firstName . $lastName;

    echo '| '.$sn_display.' ';
    }
}
echo ' |';
```

Then I realized how to use an array syntax similar to what I previously submitted:

```
$submissions = array (  
    array(
        'Jim' => 'Jones' , 
    ),
    array(
        'Tina' => 'Tim' , 
    ),
    array(
        '' => '' , 
    ),
    array(
        'Lazer' => 'Lisa' , 
    )
);

foreach ($submissions as $full_name) {
    foreach ($full_name as $firstName => $lastName) {
        if ($firstName != '') {

            $fn = $firstName;
            $ln = $lastName;

            $sn_display = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
            $sn_slug = $firstName . $lastName;

            echo '| '.$sn_display.' ';
        }
    }
}
echo ' |';
```

Both give me useful output:

```
| Jim Jones | Tina Tim | Lazer Lisa  |
```

I'm still curious - is there a more elegant way of doing this?

---

### ORIGINAL

I'm trying to take an array like this, which is going to be populated via a WordPress Gravity Forms submission:

```
$submissions = array (  
    array( 'fn' => 'Jim' , 'ln' => 'Jones' ),
    array( 'fn' => 'Tim' , 'ln' => 'Tomb' ),
    array( 'fn' => '' ,  'ln' => '' ),
    array( 'fn' => 'Lisa' , 'ln' => 'Lazer' )
);
```

and achieve a couple of goals

1. the form may have empty submissions - they must be discarded
2. the output must be useful as a string - I need to build user IDs / fill out user meta data with the strings

Using the following, I can output the data:

```
foreach($submissions as $submit) {   //break down the array
    if ($submit != '') {                 //check for empties
        foreach($submit as $key => $value){  //cycle through each subarray

            echo $value. ' ';                    //get the info - the problem: I cant isolate the values as strings

        }
    }
}
```

My output is not useful:
`| Jim | Jones | Tim | Tomb | Lisa | Lazer  |`

Especially because I want to fire a function that uses `$value` for each user - not for each users first and last name!

How can I get get my hands on the first and last names as strings in this loop? If I can get the first and last as strings, I can concatenate them when I want and use them in meta data when I want.

```
foreach($submissions as $submit) {   //break down the array
    if (implode('', $submit) != '') {    //check for empties
        foreach($submit as $key => $value){  //cycle through each subarray

            $fn = $value?Looking for this code?; //I want to make strings!
            $ln = $value?Looking for this code?; //One for each value.

            $display_name = $fn . ' ' . $ln;     // With strings I can make stuff
            $name_slug = $fn . $ln;

/* More functions will happen as we cycle through each 
submission that has user data until all the user data submissions
have been handled */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you will, because $value isn't an array, it's a scalar..... change `echo '| '.$value[0]. ' ';` to `echo '| '.$value. ' ';`

Comment: However, `if ($submit != '')` won't work the way you expect because you're comparing an array with a scalar string.... `if (implode('', $submit) != '')`

Comment: You could also use if( is_array($submit) ) ....

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the first part of the $value string with $value[0].
Just try it with:

```
$output .= ' | ' . $key . ' - ' . $value;
```

instead of

echo '| '.$value[0]. ' ';

and echo $output at the end.